# Via Plesk system - The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: ms-access, database-connection, oledb, plesk

on my local computer, I can easily run my ASP.NET project, but when trying to upload it to the server, using a button that cause a connection to my data base I'm getting this error.

Doesn't PLESK support the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider?

If it does, how can I fix this error ?
If it doesn't - should I try a different way to connect to my database?

Thank you all :)

Comment: Plesk doesn't determine what's supported, your hosting provider does. Talk with them. Since this is about what a specific hosting provider supports, your question is off-topic here.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to connect to a database without using the OLEDB?

Well, if the hosting provider tell me that the it is not supported, is there a way I can use a kind of "launcher" so it will be supported or something like this ?